# SQL Server Management Studio - Add columns containing software name and version to SQL Query for systems with specific software

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to query for computers with a specific software in SQL Server database. Unfortunately, I am completely new to SQL so I am trying to learn on the fly. I was able to create a basic query thanks to help on [Prajwal's site](https://forums.prajwaldesai.com/threads/sql-query-to-find-the-application-installed.277/).

However I would like to refine it a little bit. I want to have two extra columns which display the software name, and the software version.

To start, here is my code so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sys.Netbios_Name0 AS [Computer Name],
    sys.User_Name0 AS [User Name]
FROM
    v_R_System sys
JOIN 
    v_Add_Remove_Programs arp ON sys.ResourceID = arp.ResourceID
WHERE
    sys.ResourceID IN (SELECT sys.ResourceID
                       FROM v_R_System sys
                       JOIN v_Add_Remove_Programs arp ON sys.ResourceID = arp.ResourceID
                       WHERE DisplayName0 LIKE '%Adobe Reader%')
```

This returns the following output:

```
Computer Name | User Name
--------------+-----------
COMPUTER001   | Jane Doe  
COMPUTER002   | John Doe
```

However I would like output like the below example, with the software name from the where statement as well as its version:

```
Computer Name | User Name | Software     | Version
--------------+-----------+--------------+---------
COMPUTER001   | Jane Doe  | Adobe Reader |  v.XXX
COMPUTER002   | John Doe  | Adobe Reader |  v.XXX
```

I have tried adding to my Select statement these properties:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sys.Netbios_Name0 AS [Computer Name],
    sys.User_Name0 AS [User Name],
    arp.DisplayName0 AS [Software],
    arp.Version0 AS [Version]
```

But this returns EVERY software a computer has, like so:

```
Computer Name | User Name | Software     | Version
--------------+-----------+--------------+--------
COMPUTER001   | Jane Doe  | Adobe Reader |  v.XXX
COMPUTER001   | Jane Doe  | Firefox      |  v.XXX
COMPUTER001   | Jane Doe  | Chrome       |  v.XXX
```

I need it just to give the specific software I query. I have searched on the internet to see if I could find anything to help me, and started learning some SQL basics, but haven't had much luck so far. I am going to continue researching and working on it, but if anyone can offer me any tips or advice, I would really appreciate it!

By the way, I have managed to create the query successfully in SCCM, but I am not so sure how to translate WQL into SQL and work wants me to make the query in SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't really need an inner query (which is BTW **bad** practice and should be avoided at all costs, since this query runs on every row). You query can be simplified to code below to achieve what you need.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    sys.Netbios_Name0 AS [Computer Name],
    sys.User_Name0 AS [User Name],
    arp.DisplayName0 AS [Software],
    arp.Version0 AS [Version]
FROM v_R_System sys
JOIN v_Add_Remove_Programs arp ON sys.ResourceID = arp.ResourceID
WHERE arp.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Adobe Reader%'
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, that's brilliant! It worked perfectly, and is much cleaner as well. I appreciate the tip on avoiding inner queries, and I will remember that for future queries I do. Appreciate the help!